# can't start gnome due to bad blocks

Tags: arch-linux, badblocks

I just updated my Arch distribution. But now when I try to log in nothing happens and the below output gets written to the logs. I assume that GNOME can't be started becuase some files it needs live on damaged disk parts. If that's true, how can I repair the installation?

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-02-12 09:05:12 CET, end at Wed 2020-02-12 09:21:05 CET. --
Feb 12 09:05:42 jo gdm-password][46226]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40000 action 0x0
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3: SError: { CommWake }
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: cmd 25/00:00:28:ef:79/00:01:16:00:00/e0 tag 2 dma 131072 in
                                    res 51/40:00:28:ef:79/00:01:16:00:00/f6 Emask 0x9 (media error)
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: error: { UNC }
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 377089832 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: cmd 25/00:08:28:ef:79/00:00:16:00:00/e0 tag 13 dma 4096 in
                                    res 51/40:08:28:ef:79/00:00:16:00:00/f6 Emask 0x9 (media error)
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: error: { UNC }
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 377089832 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: cmd 25/00:08:28:ef:79/00:00:16:00:00/e0 tag 14 dma 4096 in
                                    res 51/40:08:28:ef:79/00:00:16:00:00/f6 Emask 0x9 (media error)
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: ata3.00: error: { UNC }
Feb 12 09:05:43 jo kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 377089832 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

Comment: Busted disk/corruped filesystem. Rescue whatever you can, reinstall.

Comment: Note that you probably don't need to necessarily reinstall the entire OS from scratch.  If you copy everything to a new drive and get it bootable, reinstalling all packages (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks#Reinstalling_all_packages) would save you a bunch of reconfiguring.